# Question on equipotent sets and injective function

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

My textbook begins the chapter on equipotent sets like this: (English is not my first language so I'm sorry for poor choice of words/ terminology)

> If we have $2$ sets $A$ and $B$ with a finite number of elements, it's theoretically easy to see whether they have the same number of elements. We do the following thing: we take one element of the set $A$ and one element of set $B$ and pair them. If we continue that process, after finitely many steps we will have one of the following situations:
>
> $1.$ There are no unpaired elements in $A$ and no unpaired elements in $B$.
>
> $2.$ The set $B$ doesn't contain any unpaired elements.
>
> $3.$ The set $A$ doesn't contain any unpaired elements.
>
> In the first case we constructed a bijection from set $A$ to $B$ and it's evident that $A$ and $B$ have the same number of elements.
>
> In the second case, we constructed an injection from $B$ to $A$ and it's evident that $A$ has more elements than $B$.
>
> In the third case, we constructed an injection from $A$ to $B$ and it's evident that $B$ has more elements than $A$.

Question: In the second case, why did we pick injection from $B$ to $A$?  Wouldn't a function from $A$ to $B$ also be injective? And similarly for the third case, why not from $B$ to $A$?

Comment: In the second case, there are elements in $A$ which are not related to elements in $B$ (since all elements in $B$ are related to elements in $A$). By definition of a map/function, we only have a map from $B$ to $A$, not from $A$ to $B$ (recall that a map $f:X \to Y$ relates $\textbf{every}$ element of $X$ with some element in $Y$)! The same holds for the third case.

Comment: @Student Ohhhhhh, right....Thanks so much!

Comment: The 3 situations should be **mutually exclusive**, which is not the case. Situation 1 is a **special case** of situation 2, and also of situation 3. The conclusion about existence of injections is not harmed by that, because every bijection is also an injection. But the conclusions "$A$ has **more** elements than $B$" in 2, and "$B$ has more elements than $A$" in 3) are not okay. In the special case described as situation 1 both sets have the same number of elements.

Comment: E.g. situation 2 must be described as:"$B$ does not contain unpaired elements **and** we are not in situation 1".

Answer (score 0):

Let's see about case number 2. So basically you're pairing the elements of $A$ and $B$. Now, since the set $B$ contains no unpaired elements that would mean that $A$ has more elements than $B$. Basically in that case it makes more sense to make an injection from $B$ to $A$ to prove that, since in that case all elements from $B$ would be 'hit', but not all elements from A would, thus you conclude $B$ has less elements. If you would try to make an injection from A to $B$, from all elements of $A$ you would fail, since $A$ has more elements, and if $f: A \rightarrow B$ takes all elements of $A$, not all will have a unique element in $B$, thus it won't be an injection.

Comment: My question is silly... You can't make an injection from $A$ to $B$ since mapping $A\rightarrow B$ wouldn't be a function!

Comment: @Lewis If it's all clear now that's great! :)

Comment: Statement "$B$ contains no unpaired elements" does not allow us to conclude that "$A$ has more elements than $B$". This because the statement does not exclude that also $A$ contains no unpaired elements.

Comment: Pardon, my mistake, it is more or equal! I forgot to add that! And thank you!